# Edit my input on a to-do list after submiting

Tags: javascript, html

An edit feature where i can correct an input after submitting them. [Creating a to-do list.]

```
<script>

function bigImg(x) {

  x.style.height = "74px";

  x.style.width = "74px";

}

function normalImg(x) {

  x.style.height = "39px";

  x.style.width = "39px";
}



submitForm = (value, displayer) => {

    let input = document.getElementById(value);

    let valueHolder = document.getElementById(displayer);

    let inputValue = input.value;

    valueHolder.innerHTML = inputValue;
};

const form = document.getElementById('formSubmission');

form.addEventListener('submit', (e) => {

    e.preventDefault();

    submitForm('inputData', 'valueHolder');

});


div id="myDIV" class="header">

  <h2>My To Do List</h2>

  <input type="text" id="myInput" placeholder="My List...">

  <span onclick="newElement()" class="addBtn">Add</span>

</div>






<ul id="myUL">

  <li>Hit the gym</li>

  <li class="checked">Pay bills</li>

  <li>Meet George</li>

  <li>Buy eggs</li>

  <li>Read a book</li>

  <li>Organize office</li>

</ul>
```

Example:- So if i add a task saying Buy 5 eggs. But i need 2eggs. I need not Delete the Entire task. Instead i just edit my Task saying Buy 2eggs.

Answer (score 0):

Not so simple, but here is a possible starting point for what you are trying to accomplish:

```js
function bigImg(x) {

  x.style.height = "74px";

  x.style.width = "74px";

}

function normalImg(x) {

  x.style.height = "39px";

  x.style.width = "39px";
}



submitForm = (value, displayer) => {

  let input = document.getElementById(value);
  let inputValue = input.value;
  
  const task = inputValue.replace(/[\d]/g, '').replace('  ', ' ');
  let valueHolder = document.querySelector('li[data-task="' + task + '"]');
  if (!valueHolder) {
    valueHolder = document.createElement('li');
    valueHolder.dataset.task = task;
    document.getElementById('myUL').appendChild(valueHolder);
  }

  valueHolder.innerHTML = inputValue;
};

const form = document.getElementById('formSubmission');

form.addEventListener('submit', (e) => {

  e.preventDefault();

  submitForm('inputData', 'valueHolder');

});
```

```html
<div id="myDIV" class="header">

  <h2>My To Do List</h2>
  <form id="formSubmission">
    <input type="text" id="inputData" placeholder="My List...">
  </form>
  <span onclick="newElement()" class="addBtn">Add</span>

</div>

<ul id="myUL">

  <li data-task="Hit the gym">Hit the gym</li>

  <li data-task="Pay bills">Pay bills</li>

  <li data-task="Meet George">Meet George</li>

  <li data-task="Buy eggs">Buy eggs</li>

  <li data-task="Read book">Read a book</li>

  <li data-task="Organize office">Organize office</li>

</ul>
```